# How to remove collection filter from Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, filter, remove

I want to add filter to grid. When I add filter to `sales_billing_agreement`, I got the following error.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'store_id' in where clause is ambiguous, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sp_sales_billing_agreement` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `sp_customer_entity` AS `ce` ON ce.entity_id = main_table.customer_id
 LEFT JOIN `sp_customer_entity_varchar` AS `firstname` ON firstname.entity_id = main_table.customer_id AND firstname.entity_type_id = 1 AND firstname.attribute_id = '5'
 LEFT JOIN `sp_customer_entity_varchar` AS `middlename` ON middlename.entity_id = main_table.customer_id AND middlename.entity_type_id = 1 AND middlename.attribute_id = '6'
 LEFT JOIN `sp_customer_entity_varchar` AS `lastname` ON lastname.entity_id = main_table.customer_id AND lastname.entity_type_id = 1 AND lastname.attribute_id = '7' WHERE (`store_id` IN(2))
```

Here is the PHP code

```
$this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('store_id', array('in' => $storeIds))->load();
```

Due to the error above, I update the PHP code to this,

```
try {
        $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('store_id', array('in' => $storeIds))->load();
        } catch (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception $e) {
            $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('main_table.store_id', array('in' => $storeIds))->load();
    }
```

And then, the same error occurred, and I found that the previous filter is still there. Here is the new error.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'store_id' in where clause is ambiguous, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sp_sales_billing_agreement` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `sp_customer_entity` AS `ce` ON ce.entity_id = main_table.customer_id
 LEFT JOIN `sp_customer_entity_varchar` AS `firstname` ON firstname.entity_id = main_table.customer_id AND firstname.entity_type_id = 1 AND firstname.attribute_id = '5'
 LEFT JOIN `sp_customer_entity_varchar` AS `middlename` ON middlename.entity_id = main_table.customer_id AND middlename.entity_type_id = 1 AND middlename.attribute_id = '6'
 LEFT JOIN `sp_customer_entity_varchar` AS `lastname` ON lastname.entity_id = main_table.customer_id AND lastname.entity_type_id = 1 AND lastname.attribute_id = '7' WHERE (`store_id` IN(2)) AND (`main_table`.`store_id` IN(2))
```

Is there a way to remove the previous filter before adding the new filter?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do with **Zend_Db_Select**

```
    $select = clone $collection->getSelect();
    $select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS);
    $select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
    $select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_COUNT);
    $select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_OFFSET);
    $where = $select->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::WHERE);
    foreach($where as $key=>$part) {
        if(strpos($part, "store_id") !== false) {

           // set your condition here with store id
            if($key == 0) {
                $where[$key] = "1";
            } else {
                unset($where[$key]);
            }

        }
    }
    $select->setPart(Zend_Db_Select::WHERE, $where);
```

you can remove **$select->reset** if it is not useful to you

let me know if anything i can help you more in this.

Comment: Thanks, @liyakat. I actually don't need to change the where clause, so I directly get the $select object from the collection, `$select = $collection->getSelect();`. And reset where clause, `$select->reset(Zend_Db_Select::WHERE);`. And this removes the previous filter, then I add new filter `$this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('main_table.store_id', array('in' => $storeIds))->load();`, and everything works.

Comment: @Charles, i am so glad i could help you here.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the entries of the respected grid on which filters are applied from `ui_bookmark` table.

Hope it will fix the issue

Comment: tell me did it work for you?

Comment: this is a magento 2 table,,, not 1